# How make attribute unique in xsd?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xsd-validation

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:configuration 
  xsi:schemaLocation = 
    "http://text.ru/sv/ATMScenario/ScreenConfiguration
     ATMScreenConfiguration.xsd " 
  xmlns:p="http://text.ru/sv/ATMScenario/ScreenConfiguration" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <p:screen screenNumber="001" 
    screenName="Do you need more time" />
  <p:screen screenNumber="002" 
    screenName="Do you need more time" />
  <p:screen screenNumber="004" 
    screenName="Currency prefix for amount entry" />
  <p:screen screenNumber="004" 
    screenName="Thousands separator for amount entry" />
</p:configuration>
```

XSD:

```
...
<xsd:element name="configuration" 
  type="configuration.configuration.type">
  <xsd:unique name="uConfiguration">
    <xsd:selector xpath="screen" /> 
    <xsd:field xpath="@screenNumber" /> 
  </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

I want attribute 'screenNumber' of 'screen' tag be unique. Where have I  made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

probably due to namespaces, try prefixing the selector:

```
    <xsd:unique name="uConfiguration">
        <xsd:selector xpath="p:screen"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@screenNumber"/>
    </xsd:unique>
```